# On start, display a page on chromecast instead of default image slideshow

Tags: google-cast

I have a problem. As far as my understanding of chromecast goes, it connects to the local home wifi and allows anyone connected to the same wifi to cast to it. Now the problem is that in a business setting there are a few privacy concerns. What if someone is able to cast adult content on a device in use by an another person.

I looked through Google's documentation but from what I see every app has it's own receiver who's URL is fetched through Google's servers. What I'm trying to do is configure the cast to display a code before any media is even sent to the chromecast in the first place. So before the cast icon is pressed, a device trying to cast to the chromecast must first establish a one to one connection with it and no other device will be able to connect to it after. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

At this moment there isn't anything in place to support this. Best we can do is probably something like this where the devices are set up with explicit content filters https://support.google.com/googlenest/answer/9141219?hl=en